# Where my perl programm is leaking memory?

Tags: perl, memory-leaks

I am passing 2 maps having 10 million rows (1 rows is of max 200 char) to below function. This function is causing outof memory error.  I am new to perl, Can someone help me to figure out where i am causing memory leak.

```
sub createDataFile{
my($rowIdToBatchIdMap_ref, $batchIdToNFSFileNameMap_ref, $reportDataCsvFileName, $reportDataCsvFileNameToCreate) = @_;

open FILETOREAD, $reportDataCsvFileName or die "unable to open a  file $reportDataCsvFileName for reading reports data. $!";
open FILETOWRITE, ">".$reportDataCsvFileNameToCreate or die "unable to open a  file $reportDataCsvFileNameToCreate for writing reports data. $!";

my $countOfReportHavingNullBatchId = 0;
my $countOfMissingBatchIdInBatchTable = 0;
my $countOfMissingTransRefNoInReportTable = 0;

#reading file line by line
while(<FILETOREAD>){

    my @fields = split( ',', $_ );
    my $reportRowId = $fields[0];

    if(! exists($rowIdToBatchIdMap_ref->{$reportRowId})){
        $logger->log(Debug  => "key do not exist in rowIdToBatchIdMap for row id $reportRowId");
        my $replacedLine = $fields[0]. ",," . $fields[1];
        print FILETOWRITE $replacedLine;
        $countOfReportHavingNullBatchId++;
        next;
    } else {
        my $batchId = $rowIdToBatchIdMap_ref->{$reportRowId};
        $batchId = trim($batchId);

        if(! exists($batchIdToNFSFileNameMap_ref->{$batchId})){
          $logger->log(Debug  => "key do not exist in batchIdToNFSFileNameMap_ref for batch id $batchId");
          my $replacedLine = $fields[0]. ",," . $fields[1];
          print FILETOWRITE $replacedLine;
          $countOfMissingBatchIdInBatchTable++;
        } else {

            my $xmlFileName = $batchIdToNFSFileNameMap_ref->{$batchId};
            my $replacedLine = $fields[0]. "," . $xmlFileName . "," . $fields[1];
            print FILETOWRITE $replacedLine;    
        }

    }

} #end of while

$logger->log(Info => "No of reports having null batch id in REPORT_DATA table is $countOfReportHavingNullBatchId");
$logger->log(Info => "No of reports whose batch id is not present in BATCH table is $countOfMissingBatchIdInBatchTable");
close(FILETOREAD);
close(FILETOWRITE);
}
```

Comment: what's memory consumption? what amount are we talking about?

Comment: My script dies with out of memory error after using 3.5 GB which it should not use as the memory used by both input map is around 600 MB.

Comment: As far as I can see, this subroutine only uses constant memory. While it could be improved, it is most likely not the source of your problems. Are you *sure* that the out-of-memory exception is thrown during execution of this code? Where exactly does it occur? (Hunches: Maybe when opening the files, more likely something that `$logger` is doing)

Comment: You are aware that all your print statements print to the same line? (Since you have no newline) So with millions of prints, that will be a very long line indeed. Not sure how that would affect memory consumption, but if you were to try and read such a line, it would of course consume tons of memory.

Comment: @TLP `$files[-1]` should contain a newline – but that is irrelevant for memory consumption, as Perl is chunk-buffered when writing to files (when writing to a terminal, Perl flushes after each line).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a root cause. It was due to Dumper function which i was using to dump the content of a map on log file before calling the mentioned function. I removed that line and now no more getting the out of memory error.